# Validate Signature Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, openssl, digital-signature

I created an EC public key with OpenSSL:

```
openssl ecparam -name prime256v1 -genkey -noout -out ec-key.pem
openssl ec -in ec-key.pem -pubout -out ecpubkey.pem
```

How can I import it (ecpubkey.pem) and use it in my objective-c code to validate a signature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:
Creating the key using opens

```
openssl ecparam -name prime256v1 -genkey -noout -out ec-key.pem
```

Using openssl to generate **der encoded** certificate:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -key ec-key.pem -outform der -out server.pem -days 730
```

Sign the content

```
openssl dgst -sha256 -sign ec-key.pem content.txt > signature
```

Then loading the certificate

```
NSString *cerPath = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] pathForResource:@"server" ofType:@"cer"];
NSData *cerData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:cerPath];
SecCertificateRef certificate = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, (CFDataRef)cerData);
```

Extrating the public key from the certificate

```
SecPolicyRef secPolicy = SecPolicyCreateBasicX509();
SecTrustRef trust;
SecTrustCreateWithCertificates(certificate, secPolicy, &trust);
SecTrustResultType resultType;
SecTrustEvaluate(trust, &resultType);
SecKeyRef publicKey = SecTrustCopyPublicKey(trust);
```

Verifing the signature

```
uint8_t digest[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
if (!CC_SHA256([content bytes], (CC_LONG)[content length], digest)) return NO;    
OSStatus status = SecKeyRawVerify(publicKey,
                                  kSecPaddingPKCS1,
                                  digest,
                                  CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH,
                                  (uint8_t*)[signature bytes],
                                  [signature length]);

return status == errSecSuccess;
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to use EC keys in iOS is by using 3rd party library GMEllipticCurveCrypto: https://github.com/ricmoo/GMEllipticCurveCrypto. Check it out.

Comment: I'm looking for CSR with ecdsawithsha256 and I followed this library this is only for signature from EC so could you help me that how can I generate CSR (PEM format) certificate via using this library?